# C++ constructors (speed)

Tags: c++, object, constructor

I read sometimes when i am calling constructor, it creates temporary object and then copy it to true variable. So i shouldn't put some things into constructor, for example counter of created objects etc. and some syntax of creating objects should by faster than other?

```
A a(10); 
A a = 10; // temporary object?
A a = A(10); // temporary object?
```

So what type of constructor i should use?

Comment: If you compile in release (with the optimized flag) then the compiler will remove the copy (technically called elide the copy). .

Comment: @gongzhitaao, I can give you code where the latter does not compile, but the former does.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's true that a compiler is in principle allowed to generate a temporary object when you say `A a = 10;` or `A a = A(10);`, but never when you say `A a(10);`. However, the standard explicitly allows omitting this unnecessary copy, and any sane compiler will perform this optimization.

In GCC you can disallow the optimization with the flag `-fno-elide-constructors`.

---

As a formal consequence, though, the latter two forms of initialization require that the constructor `A::A(int)` not be `explicit`, while the first form (direct-initialization) works with explicit constructors, too. The notion of implicit conversion is somewhat subtle and worth keeping in mind.

Answer (score 1):

In release mode, it will make no difference as the compilers these days are good enough to optimise away the temporary object. Although in debug mode, they will probably ALL create a temporary object to allow the debugger to have a way of attaching to the creation of the object.